# How to draw tangent line at specified points in a curve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, curve

I am having a an array of points x,y and respective angles at those specified points. I want to plot a tangent line at those points, i am unable to figure out how to proceed.

http://postimg.org/image/s2y1pqqaj/

As shown in command window 1st column contains x points , 2nd column contains y points and 3rd column the respective tangent angle. Figure 1 is plot between x and y points. 
I know the slope i.e tangent angle at every point as you can see it in the 3rd column. But not able to understand how to implement it to draw tangent at these points . Also the equation for tangent line 'y = mx + b' where m - slope and b is y intercept. Thanking you.

Here is the code

```
% Fill in parr a list of points and tangents to be used for display.
% @param parr (x,y) Array of points.
% @param tan Array of tangents.
% @param lengthStep Distance between points.

 function [x y tan] = GetPointListForDisplay(m_Length,r1,r2,count)

   global nn ca ce length; 

   GetLength = m_Length;
   length = GetLength;   

   ca = GetCurvatureAtDeltaLength(0.0);     
   ce = GetCurvatureAtDeltaLength(length);

   %if ((abs(ca) < 1.0/10000.0) && (abs(ce) < 1.0/10000.0))
   %end

   radius = 1.0 ./ max(abs(ca), abs(ce));

   %if (radius < 0.1)
   %end

   nn = 3 + (180.0 * length/(2*pi*radius));  % Using modified formula of arc here

   lengthStep = length/nn; 
   currLen = -lengthStep;

   while (1) 

       currLen = currLen + lengthStep;
       if (currLen > m_Length)

           currLen = m_Length; 
       end

       [x,y] = GetPointAtDeltaLength(currLen);
       [tan] = GetTangentGridBearingAtDeltaLength(currLen); 

       z(count,1) = x;
       z(count,2)= y;
       z(count,3)= tan;

       figure(1);

       %plot(z(count,1).*sin(z(count,3)),z(count,2).*cos(z(count,3)),'b*');
       %plot(z(1,count).*cos(z(3,count)),z(2,count).*sin(z(3,count)),'b*');
       plot(z(count,1),z(count,2),'b*');
       %plot(z(1,count),z(2,count),'b*');
       hold on;

       %pause(0.1);

       count=count+1;
       axis equal;     

       if (currLen >= m_Length)
          z(count,1)= tan
          break;
       end

   end

 end
```

Regards,

Mrinal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ii = index of the point where you want to get the tangent
x1 = left bound of your tangent
x2 = right bound of your tangent
xT = z(ii,1)  %argument where you want to get the tangent
yT = z(ii,2)  %corresponding y
mT = tan(z(ii,3))   % corresponding slope
```

I assume you just want one tangent, then plot it like this.

```
plot( [x1,xT,x2] , [yT-mT*(xT-x1), yT, yT+mT*(x2-xT)] )
```

Otherwise just use a loop for more tangents using `ii` as iteration variable.

The string for your equation would be

```
eq = strcat('y = ',num2str(mT),'*x + ',num2str(yT-mT*xT))
```

Comment: Thank you but i am unable to understand how can i use the above equation in my code. Here is my code as i am using various functions, so it is not possible for me to upload the whole code but the function in which i am using this is below. Hope you can guide. I am uploading my code in the ques above.

Comment: Your code above is not relevant for your question. i just used your matrix `z`. you have to define `ii`,`x1` and `x2` by yourself. Try to understand what I was posting, you just have to put it under your code. I actually neither get your empty if-conditions above.

Comment: Okay . i will do as you suggested and sorry i forgot to erase that if condition, i will do it now.